# Firebase Login nothing happens

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data stored (username & password) in my Firebase database. Whenever I click login, nothing happens.

Could someone please tell me where I am going wrong? I've wasted countless hours already trying to find the answer. I have added the stack trace below, this is when I try to debug from `user`

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    Button login, register;
    EditText et1, et2;
    TextView tv1;
    int count = 3;

    //Firebase database/reference variables.
    //FirebaseDatabase database;
    //DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButtonHome);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerButton);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userLogin);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userPassword);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignin);
        //login button on the app
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (validateUser() | validatePass()){
                } else{
                    user();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void loginButton(View view) {
    }

    private void user() {

        final String username = et1.getEditableText().toString().trim();
        final String password = et1.getEditableText().toString().trim();

        //reference to db in firebase
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
        Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(username); reference.orderByChild("password").equalTo(password);
        checkUser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    String pwFromDB = snapshot.child(username).child("password").getValue(String.class);
                    if (pwFromDB.equals(password)){
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityArray.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void registerButton(View view) {

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new NewUserActivity();
                if (view.isShown()){ //will hide register button after selection.
                    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }else {
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Redirecting to Register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewUserActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }
    private Boolean validateUser (){
        String val = et1.getEditableText().toString();

        if (val.isEmpty()){
            et1.setError("Field Cannot Be Empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            et1.setError(null);
            return true;
        }
    }

    private Boolean validatePass () {
        String val = et2.getEditableText().toString();

        if (val.isEmpty()){
            et2.setError("Field Cannot Be Empty");
            return false;
        } else {
            et2.setError(null);
            return false;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Stack Trace Output

```
f stackTrace = {StackTraceElement[19]@3979}
•   Os {StackTraceElement@3983;> "libcore.io.Posix.stat(NativeMethod)" Navigate
•   1 s (StackTraceElement@3984) "libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.stat(BlockGuardOs.java:293)“ Navigate
•   2 s {StackTraceElement@3985; "java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:522)" Navigate
•   3 s {StackTraceElement@3986} "dalvik.system.DexPathList.makePathElements(DexPathlistjava:232)“ Navigate
•   4 s {StackTraceElement@3987} ”dalvik.system.DexPathList<init>(DexPathlist.java:139)" Navigate
•   5 s {StackTraceElement@3988> "dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassloader.java:48)“ Navigate
•   6 s {StackTraceElement@3989> "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassloader.java:65)" Navigate
•   7s {StackTraceElement@3990) "android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(Applicationloaders.java:58r Navigate
•   8 s {StackTraceElement@399l “android.app.loadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApkjava:376)“ Navigate
•   9 s {StackTraceElement@3992} ”android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:568)" . Navigate
•   10 = (StackTraceElement@3993) “android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4680)" Navigate
•   11 s {StackTraceElement@3994j "android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)‘ Navigate
•   12 = {StackTraceElement@3995j ”android.app.ActivityThreadSH.handleMessage(ActivityThreadjava:1405)“ .. Navigate
•   13 = {StackTraceElement@3996j "android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)" Navigate
•   14 = (StackTraceElement@3997) "android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)M Navigate
•   15 = {StackTraceElement@3998] "android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)" Navigate
•   16 = (StackTraceElement@3999) "java.lang.reflectMethod.invoke(Native Method)" .. Navigate
•   17 = (StackTraceElement@4000) "com.android.internal.os.Zygotelnit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygotelnitjava:726)" Navigate
•   18 = (StackTraceElement@4001) -com.android.internal.os.Zygotelnit.main(Zygotelnit.java:616)“ Navigate
```

Comment: "Nothing happens" is really hard to help with. It's much better if you can tell us what **did** happen, and where code stopped doing what you expected. For example, does your `user` method get called? It's best to check this by setting a breakpoint in that method and then running in a debugger. If it does reach there, does it ever get into the `onDataChange` method (same method: place a breakpoint in it). If not, please never leave `onCancelled` empty. At a minimum it should be: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have tried using debug at `user` and the output gives me  ErrnoException@3973 I am not sure if that means anything.

Nothing is happening when I try to login using. To something **did** happen would be great for me :) 

Any other suggestions?

Comment: getValue(String.class) try .toString() instead

Comment: @VasiaZaretskyi No, that did nothing to change my outcome. It seems as though my `user` method is not even being reached into when I hit login (onClickListener) My `Toast` message is not displaying either...
`String pwFromDB = snapshot.child(username).child("password").toString();
                    if (pwFromDB.equals(password)){
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ActivityArray.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: @VasiaZaretskyi That's actually an anti-pattern, since it turns a type-safe `getValue(String.class)` call into a typeless call.

Comment: @SJD: Did you implement `onCancelled` as I said? Also: please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to add the exact error message and stack trace you get.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added `@Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                throw error.toException();
            }` Still nothing happening for me when I try read the `users` data from firebase

Comment: Please don't add large chunks of code or logging to comments, as they're unreadable. Edit your question by clicking the link under it, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to make them readable. That will also make your question eligible to be reopened.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Question now edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your onClick method to this one. You used | insted of ||.
And if/else can be simplified

```
login.setOnClickListener(view -> {
    if (!(validateUser() || validatePass())) user();
});
```

Comment: No, that did fix the issue... Still does not even  display the Toast message 'welcome'
`login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!(validateUser() || validatePass())) user();
            }
        }); `